# How to tackle the integral $\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{-1+\sqrt{\frac{4}{x}-3}} d x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

$ \text {Let } y=\sqrt{-1+\sqrt{\frac{4}{x}-3}}\textrm{ then ,}$
$ \displaystyle \begin{aligned}I&=16 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{y^{2}\left(y^{2}+1\right) d y}{\left(y^{4}+2 y^{2}+4\right)^{2}}\\&=4\left[3 \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{y^{2}\left(y^{2}+2\right)}{\left(y^{4}+2 y^{2}+4\right)^{2}} d y}_{J}+\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{y^{2}\left(y^{2}-2\right)}{\left(y^{4}+2 y^{2}+4\right)^{2}}}_{K} d y\right] \end{aligned}\tag*{} $
Now let’s play a little trick on the integral $ J$.
$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}J &=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1+\frac{2}{y^{2}}}{\left(y^{2}+\frac{4}{y^{2}}+2\right)^{2}} d y \\&=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d\left(y-\frac{2}{y}\right)}{\left[\left(y-\frac{2}{y}\right)^{2}+6\right]^{2}} \\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d u}{\left(u^{2}+6\right)^{2}}\\ &\stackrel{u=\sqrt6 \tan \theta}{=}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sqrt{6} \sec ^{2} \theta d \theta}{\left(6 \sec ^{2} \theta\right)^{2}}\\&=\frac{\pi}{12 \sqrt{6}} \end{aligned} \tag*{} $
For the integral $ K$ , we first split the interval into two.
$ \displaystyle \begin{aligned}K &=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-\frac{2}{y^{2}}}{\left(y^{2}+\frac{4}{y^{2}}+2\right)^{2}} d y \\&=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1-\frac{1}{y^{2}}}{\left(y^{2}+\frac{4}{y^{2}}+2\right)^{2}} d y+\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1-\frac{2}{y^{2}}}{\left(y^{2}+\frac{4}{y}+2\right)^{2}} d y \\&=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{d\left(y+\frac{2}{y}\right)}{\left[\left(y+\frac{2}{y}\right)^{2}-2\right]^{2}}+\int_{3}^{\infty} \frac{d\left(y+\frac{2}{y}\right)}{\left[\left(y+\frac{2}{y}\right)^{2}-2\right]^{2}} d y \\&=\int_{\infty}^{3} \frac{d u}{\left(u^{2}-2\right)^{2}}+\int_{3}^{\infty} \frac{d v}{\left(v^{2}-2\right)^{2}} \\&=0 \end{aligned} \tag*{} $
Now we can conclude that
$\displaystyle \boxed{I=4\left(3 \cdot \frac{\pi}{12 \sqrt{6}}\right)=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6}}}\tag*{} $

***My Question***

Is there any other substitution or method to tackle the integral?

Comment: Thank you for your interesting suggestion

Answer (score 6):

Taking the inverse function $x=x(y)$ and integrating between $0$ and $\infty$ gives that:

$\int_0^\infty \frac{4}{y^{4}+2y^{2}+4}dy$,

Decomposing the rational function into the sum of several simple fractions gives:

$\frac{4}{(y^{2}+\sqrt{2}y+2)( y^{2}-\sqrt{2}y+2)}=$,

$\frac{A y+B}{ y^{2}+\sqrt{2}y+2}+\frac{C y+D}{ y^{2}-\sqrt{2}y+2}$,

$A=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},B=1, C=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, D=1$.

Integrating between $0$ and $\infty$, we get:

$\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6}}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int_0^1\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{4}{x}-3}-1}dx$$
We delay our substitution with an intermediate step. Start with integration by parts. We will set $u$ equal to the integrand, and $dv=dx$. This step will also prepare our substitution.
$$u=\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{4}{x}-3}-1}⇒du=d\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{4}{x}-3}-1}\right)$$
$$dv=dx⇒v=x$$
$$I=\int_0^1xd\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{4}{x}-3}-1}\right)$$
Substitute $u=\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{4}{x}-3}-1},\space x=\frac{4}{u^4+2u^2+4}$. Notice that $du$ is already prepared. This results in a simple integral.
$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{4du}{u^4+2u^2+4}$$
Substitute $u→\sqrt2u $
$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{4\sqrt2dx}{4u^4+4u^2+4}=\sqrt2\int_{0}^\infty\frac{du}{u^4+u^2+1}$$Split the integral at $x=1$ and invert the integral within $[1,\infty)$ with $u\rightarrow\frac{1}{u}$, forming the following integral.
Prepare for substitution.$$=\sqrt2\int_{0}^1\frac{1+u^2}{u^4+u^2+1}du=\sqrt2\int_0^1\frac{1+u^{-2}}{u^2+u^{-2}+1}du=\sqrt2\int_0^1\frac{d(u-u^{-1})}{(u-u^{-1})^2+3}$$$$=\sqrt2\int_0^\infty\frac{dv}{v^2+3}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt6}$$

Final answer
$$I=\int_0^1\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac{4}{x}-3}-1}dx=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt6}$$

Answer (score 0):

We can rewrite the integrand as a rational function with just a few substitutions:

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^1 \sqrt{-1+\sqrt{\frac{4}{x}-3}} \, dx \\[1ex]
&= 8 \int_0^1 \sqrt x \sqrt{1-x} \, \frac{dx}{(3x^2+1)^2} \tag{1} \\[1ex]
&= 16 \int_0^\infty \frac{x^2 (x^2+1)}{\left(x^4+2x^2+4\right)^2} \, dx \tag{2}
\end{align*}$$

- $(1)$ : substitute $x\mapsto\frac{4x^2}{3x^2+1}$
- $(2)$ : substitute $x\mapsto\sqrt{\frac{1-x}x}$

and this could probably be made even simpler. But we can evaluate the current form quite readily with complex analysis.

Let $\mathcal I=2I$ be the same integral but taken over the entire real line. Replace $x$ with complex $z$ and integrate along a semicircular contour with radius $R>\sqrt2$. It's easy to see the integral over the circular arc will vanish as $R\to\infty$, and all we need to do is add up the residues at the order-$2$ poles $z=\frac{\pm1+i\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}$.